# What's the term/aphorism for a security practice where access equals authorization?

Tags: authorization, theory

I read about a concept that went something like "**access equals authorization**," the idea being that there is something secured, and if someone manages to get into it, then they have proven themselves to be allowed to see it. Essentially, the set of those authorized is equal to the set of those who have gained access.

Examples of this idea off the top of my head:

- A lockpicker's convention where the door is locked: if you can pick the lock, you're allowed into the convention.
- An invitation to apply for a job hidden in the source code of a website or program: anyone who has found it is probably at least skilled enough to warrant an interview.
- The door to Moria in Lord of the Rings: the password is "friend" in Elvish, and the door tells you to say the word "friend". It's assumed that anyone able to read and speak Elvish must necessarily be good or aligned with those who built it.
- Thor's hammer, Mjolnir: only those worthy to wield its power are able to lift it, so anyone who can wield it is necessarily worthy of it. (C.f. the many "pure of heart" requirements in fantasy)

Obviously this is more of a gimmick or a writing trope than anything else, but still, the question nags at me. **What's the name or aphorism that describes this concept?**

Comment: I'm not sure that this is a "security practice" or theory. What you describe s just a test. No authorisation, no authentication. Just an access test.

Comment: What makes these examples different from someone knowing the password and thus getting access? Its basically the same: a proof of some specific knowledge/capability which others don't have. I don't think there is a separate term which includes all the examples you mention but does not include password based authentication too.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich the difference is knowing/passing a secret that is known/checked on the other side. That's fundamentally different from figuring out how to access the resource. It's the difference between credential checking and port knocking. One requires *verification*, the other doesn't.

Comment: @Steff A password can be stolen, as can a key. In those cases, someone you didn't intend is gaining access. In this case, the theory is that anyone who can pass the test or gain access is someone we want to gain access, i.e. there are no unauthorized entrants, by definition. You could still have people "cheat"-someone else picks the lock and holds the door open, etc, but I'm talking about the principle of the thing.

Comment: @AosSidhe: Based on this I would argue that this is included in "something you are" - together with biometric and behavior based authentication like fingerprint, iris, style of typing on the keyboard ...